# Is it good to use DynamoDB for read-only write-once data?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I got a database of my country postal code with its respective district.  (https://github.com/pentagonal/Indonesia-Postal-Code/blob/master/Json/postal_array.json )(about 13 MB in JSON)

Is it good to use DynamoDB for this read-only data?
Because I never write to the database except just for initial commit.

Please give me advice which way to go. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can, but if the data is constant why not just minify the json and include it in your application? Or just include it as constant data?

DynamoDB seems like overkill to me.

Comment: Yeah, if you are only going to write once, then using DynamoDB may indeed be an overkill. However, are you using a database already in other parts of your application? If so I would just store the postal code in whatever you are already using.  If you are not already  using another DB and you still want to put it in a DB, then maybe SQLlite may be a better good choice.

Comment: @camba1 Yes, I already use DynamoDB but I want my cost to be efficient and effective